# Is there way to specify more resources for Google App Engine during build stage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Let me start with context. I have react app that takes around 8192MB to during build. Deployment to GAE has been failing as fax memory we can have is 3072 MB (using instance_class: F4_1G).

I was wondering we can we specify more resources during build on GAE deployment? After build app can run in smaller server like F2 (768 MB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems GAE doesn't have option to define higher resources during build and change that after. Besides that GAE is max F4_1G (3072 MB, 2.4 GHz). So I decided on a different approach.

1. Use cloud build to build (where we can provision machines with higher resources)
2. on app.yaml, override standard npm build with blank.

So my cloudbuild.yaml looks like:

```
    steps:
      - name: 'node:14.21-buster'
        entrypoint: 'npm'
        args: ['install']
      - name: 'node:14.21-buster'
        entrypoint: 'npm'
        args: ['run', 'build']
        env:
          - NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
          - GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false

      .... MORE STEPS HERE .....

      - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
        entrypoint: 'gcloud'
        args: ['app', 'deploy']

    substitutions:
      _CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE: us-central1-c
      _CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_REGION: us-central1

    options:
      machine_type: E2_HIGHCPU_8
```

app.yaml looks like:

```
    runtime: nodejs14
    build_env_variables:
      GOOGLE_NODE_RUN_SCRIPTS: '' # prevent running npm run build on GAE
    entrypoint: node server/server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the Google App Engine Flex [Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible). This has an option to configure all the resource settings in app.yaml.

For example you can check this configuration:

```
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 10
  volumes:
  - name: ramdisk1
    volume_type: tmpfs
    size_gb: 0.5
```

You can increase your memory_gb, cpu, and disk_size_gb.

To learn more about app.yaml configuration file check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/reference/app-yaml?tab=python)

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. Let me explain my need 1) higher resources during build, 2) normal server like F1 or F2 after deployment.